# python 3 simple calculator , need assistance understanding subject and completing task, new to python and coding in general

Tags: python, python-3.x, calculator

I need help programming a simple python 3 calculator, I am completely new to coding and python so my knowledge on this is low and i'm having a tough time just getting started.

heres the problem: Your assignment is to create an extremely simple calculator in Python. So simple, it can only add positive whole numbers.

Take a look at the hello.py example posted this week. It shows examples of reading data using the input() method. It shows how to write functions (using 'def'), as well as passing parameters and returning a value. It also shows how to interpolate variables into a string using the printf-style string formatting.

First create, a simple function called "add". It should take in two values and return the sum of the values.

Next create an interactive script which uses the "add" function. The output, when done, should look like this:

What is the first number?
3
What is the second number?
5
Your sum is 8.

In the example above, the bold items are typed by the user. Note that, to pass the online test, you must format your text exactly the same as above.

When done (and tested locally), test and submit online at CSGrading.com Assignment 2.

HELLO.PY CODE

```
def get_firstname():
    print("First Name: ")
    firstname = input()
    return firstname

def get_lastname():
    print("Last Name: ")
    lastname = input()
    return lastname

def say_hello(f,l):
    print("Hello %s %s" % (f,l))

say_hello(get_firstname(),get_lastname())
```

I really wanna learn this but ultimately i'm stuck.

Comment: Did you try to get started at all? If you're stuck creating an `add` function, perhaps it's time to sit down and study?

Comment: How are you stuck when you haven't even started moving yet? Where's your work? Please don't just copy and paste your assignment. This is *your* job, not mine.

Comment: def get_firstnumber():
 print("First Number: ")
 firstnumber = input(5)
 return firstnumber

def get_secondnumber():
 print("Second Number: ")
 secondnumber = input(3)
 return secondnumber 



        (get sum())          thats my work so far

Comment: @bodewriter 1. Use Google. 2. Don't skip class. 3. Edit your question. 4. Use back quotes to write a readable code.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with the first part. Your two functions currently get the first name and last name. With a little modification, we can make it so it gets numbers instead of names:

```
def get_first_number():
    print("First Number: ")
    firstnumber = int(input())
    return firstnumber
```

First, the text is changed to show the text "First number: " rather than "First name: ":

```
print("First Number: ")
```

Next, you get the input, but because it is a string, you use the `int` function to change it to an integer.

```
firstnumber = int(input())
```

Then, you return it in the same fashion.

After that, you now have this:

```
def get_first_number():
    print("First Number: ")
    firstnumber = int(input())
    return firstnumber

def get_last_number():
    print("Last Number: ")
    lastnumber = int(input())
    return lastnumber
```

Almost done, you'll now need an `add` function.

```
def addTwo(a, b):
    if a < 0:
        quit()
    if b < 0:
        quit()
    result = a + b
    return result
```

This function will just take two integers, and if they're less than zero (therefore negative), exit the program. If they are not, it returns the result of the addition.

Finally, we need a main part.

```
print(addTwo(get_first_number(), get_last_number()))
```

All this does is prints the output of your add function when your first and second numbers are retrieved and passed to it.

Result:

```
def get_first_number():
    print("First Number: ")
    firstnumber = int(input())
    return firstnumber

def get_last_number():
    print("Last Number: ")
    lastnumber = int(input())
    return lastnumber

def addTwo(a, b):
    if a < 0:
        quit()
    if b < 0:
        quit()
    result = a + b
    return result

print("Solution: ", addTwo(get_first_number(), get_last_number()))
```